# Why am I getting "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')" when using middleware in Next.js 13?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, supabase

I am currently working on a Next.js 13 project and trying to implement middleware for authentication using the @supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs package. However, I'm encountering an error that says "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')". I am not sure why this error is occurring and how to resolve it.

Here's the code I have in my middleware.ts file:

```js
import { createMiddlewareSupabaseClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) {
  // OPTIONAL - THIS DESACTIVATES THE MIDDLEWARE IF THE ENVIRONMENT = DEVELOPMENT
  // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  //   return NextResponse.next();
  // }

  const supabase = createMiddlewareSupabaseClient({ req, res });
  const { data: { session } } = await supabase.auth.getSession();


  // destructure the data object to obtain the session object
  if (!session) {
    if (req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/signup') || req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/login')) {
      return NextResponse.next()
    }

    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', req.nextUrl));
  }

  if (session) {
    const { data: userArray, error } = await supabase.from('companies_users').select(`companies(username)`).eq('user_id', session.user.id)
    const username = userArray && userArray[0].companies.username

    if (req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/login')) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/${username}`, req.nextUrl));
    }
    if (!req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(`/${username}`)) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/${username}`, req.nextUrl));
    }
  }

}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    /*
     * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
     * - api (API routes)
     * - _next/static (static files)
     * - _next/image (image optimization files)
     * - favicon.ico (favicon file)
     */
    '/((?!api|_next|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)',
  ],
}
```

The error message I receive in the console is:

```
[TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')]
[TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')]
- error node_modules\@supabase\auth-helpers-nextjs\dist\index.js (128:26) @ set
- error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')
null
```